# 3D mesh segmentation simple algorithm

Tags: 3d, mesh

I am developing the algorithm reported in this article:

[Least square conformal mapping](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall09/Levy02.pdf).

Here is presented an algorithm to flat a 3d mesh on the parametric space, but i don't understand the segmentation step.

Does anyone know an alternative segmentation approach simpler than the algorithm presented in that article?

In other word, do you know a simple and efficient mesh segmentation algorithm?

The requirements are:

- charts boundaries should be positioned in such a way that most
  of the discontinuities between the charts will be located in zones
  where they will not cause texture artifacts,
- boundary curves corresponding to high curvature zones of the model.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Did you get what you wanted?